# Rails 4, Ruby 2.7.1 schema.rb shows "Could not dump table because of following FrozenError"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, schema, ruby-2.7

After upgrading to Ruby 2.7.1 my schema.rb is peppered with the following warnings for multiple tables:

```
# Could not dump table "pages" because of following FrozenError
#   can't modify frozen String: "false"

# Could not dump table "proxies" because of following FrozenError
#   can't modify frozen String: "true"
```

I've searched high and low for a solution and have checked (as far as I'm able) the migrations, of which there are many.
Downgrading Ruby at this staging isn't an option.

Anyone has a similar situation and managed to resolve it?

Comment: Which specific version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm running Rails 4.2.11

Comment: Tried to replicate your problem, I couldn't even run the migrations. Is there a way to reproduce your problem?

Comment: You will either need to downgrade ruby to around 2.4.5 or upgrade rails. Here is a closed issue against rails 5.x saying it 2.7 is not supported due to numerous warnings and issues:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38426

Comment: thanks @mlockerd I guess its time to upgrade Rails :|

Answer (score 8):

If someone is still looking for this.

The error is because in the old version of rails the schema dumper used the `to_s` to convert database default column value to string and then perform operations on that string. But in `ruby 2.7` the `to_s` method for `nil, true and false` return a frozen string and hence the `FrozenError`, so if upgrading rails version is not an option you can just put this in an initializer to override the schema dumper method to use the `dup` instead of actual string.

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    module ColumnDumper
      def prepare_column_options(column, types)
        spec = {}
        spec[:name]      = column.name.inspect
        spec[:type]      = column.type.to_s
        spec[:null]      = 'false' unless column.null

        limit = column.limit || types[column.type][:limit]
        spec[:limit]     = limit.inspect if limit
        spec[:precision] = column.precision.inspect if column.precision
        spec[:scale]     = column.scale.inspect if column.scale

        default = schema_default(column).dup if column.has_default?
        spec[:default]   = default unless default.nil?

        spec
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this is helped, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned that downgrading RUby isn't an option for you.

But if you are able to downgrade Ruby here's what worked for me.

This is a Ruby 2.7 issue as noted by [rmlockerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10369647/rmlockerd).

I ended up downgrading my Ruby version to '2.6.6'.

After downgrading my Ruby, I ran db:schema:load and was able regenerate the schema file without the above errors.